# DataTable select plugin and jquery event handler issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables, jquery-events

I have read several articles and `jQuery` API documentation and understand there is no difference between `click()` and `on('click')` other than event delegate.

And I'm using Datatables and its select plugin in my page; My Html Tag and script is something identical to following code.

```
<div class='panel'>
    <table class='data-table'>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Column 1</th>
                <th>Column 2</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr data-id='1'>
                <td>Row 1, 1</td>
                <td>Row 1, 2</td>
            </td>
            <tr data-id='2'>
                <td>Row 2, 1</td>
                <td>Row 2, 2</td>
            </td>
            <tr data-id='3'>
                <td>Row 3, 1</td>
                <td>Row 3, 2</td>
            </td>

        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>

<script>
    $('table tbody tr').click(function(){
        console.log("Click(): " + $('table tr.selected').data('id'));
    });
    $('table').on('click', 'tbody tr', function() {
        console.log("On(Click()): " + $('table tr.selected').data('id'));
    });
</script>
```

when `click()` and `on('click')` are same I have to get same console results, but what I got is after selecting first row (`data-id=1`)

```
On(Click()): undefined
Click(): 1
```

then on clicking second row from first

```
On(Click()): 1
Click(): 2
```

that is I see that `on('click()')` runs before data-table's selection routine and `click()` runs after same. what will be the possible fix to apply so that both `click()` and `on(click())` execute after datatables selection routine.

As the dataset in my table is huge in number I need to apply delegation i.e., `on(click())`.

### Update

using `this` in events will give access to get selected row, but clicking same row second time in data-table will remove selection, so the result should be `undefined` for both functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your jquery selector, use `this` keyword instead:

```
$('table tbody tr').click(function(){
    if($(this).hasClass( "selected" ) == true) {
        console.log("Click(): " + $(this).data('id'));
    }
});
$('.data-table').on('click', 'tbody tr', function() {
    if (!$(this).hasClass('selected'))
        console.log("On(Click()): " + $(this).data('id'));
    else
        console.log('nothing selected');
});
```

Comment: You are right but I also need to count number of rows selected or in other way I need to know weather atleast one row selected or no rows selected after current click - this is also my requirement I that forget to include in question I'll correct question.

Comment: You can check the count number using - `$( "tr.selected" ).size()`

Comment: $('tr.selected').size() return 0 initially.

Comment: Updated my answer.

Comment: but the problem here is `'selected'` class applied only after `on('click')` event.

Comment: Inspired by your answer! I found solution, updated

    `$('.data-table').on('click', 'tbody tr', function() {
        if (!$(this).hasClass('selected'))
            console.log("On(Click()): " + $(this).data('id'));
    });`